# Chatbot in Discord (W. Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am making a Discord bot with Python.

**I would like to add a feature in where, there is a channel called "chatbot", and any text typed there would be replied to by Cleverbot**

I am currently trying with the cleverbotfree library, but it doesn't work and I can't find good documentation on it. My problem is that I am trying to run this async command:

```
@CleverbotAsync.connect
 async def async_chat(bot, message, user_input, bot_prompt):
     """Example code using cleverbotfree async API with decorator."""

    reply = await bot.single_exchange(user_input)
    await message.channel.send(f'{0}'.format(reply))
    await bot.close()
```

However, I can't do this in `on_message`, because it needs to be run in this snippet of code:

```
if chnl == 'chatbot':
      #whatever running that command
```

So, I'm not sure how do it.

And yes, I have looked into and tried **Selenuim**, but it appears that whenever I click the accept button, nothing loads. (This must be a way for Cleverbot to make people actually pay for their API, which I can't do).

**Here is my full code(I know it's not the best):**

```
import discord
from discord import channel
from discord.flags import MessageFlags
from webserver import keep_alive
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import time
import asyncio
from cleverbotfree import CleverbotAsync
from cleverbotfree import Cleverbot
     

requests = []
    

def send(message,user_input,bot_prompt):
  asyncio.run(async_chat(message,user_input,'Cleverbot:'))




client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def request(ctx, request: str,member: discord.Member):
  requests.append('{0}: {1}'.format(member,request))
  await ctx.send(f'Thanks {member.metion} for the request, my dev will (hopefully) get right to work!')


@client.command(description="See what my dev is working on")
async def workingon(ctx):
  ctx.send("My Dev is currently working on adding a feature in where, in a channel called 'chatbot', it will respond like a human.(though he has spent hours on it, it still doesn't work)")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    #confirming login
    print('Logged on as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print(f'Greetings {member}, welcome to server') 

@CleverbotAsync.connect
async def async_chat(bot, message, user_input, bot_prompt):
    """Example code using cleverbotfree async api with decorator."""
    
        
      
    reply = await bot.single_exchange(user_input)
    await message.channel.send(f'{0}'.format(reply))
    await bot.close()




@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    #getting variables
    usrnm = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    msg = str(message.content)
    chnl = str(message.channel.name)
    

    if usrnm != str(client.user).split('#')[0] and msg.lower() == 'hello bot':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {usrnm}, how do you do?')
        return
    
    if str(msg).split(' ')[0].lower() == 'im':
        print(str(msg).split(' ')[0].lower())
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi, {msg}, im a dad!')

    if msg.lower() == '!newfeatures':
      await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, The newest feature added to the bot is that if a new member joins, it will greet them')

    if msg.lower() == '!help':
      await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, Type !help for help. \n\n - Typing "Hello Bot" will make the bot answer\n - typing "im" before anything will make the bot answer\n - Typing !newfeatures will tell you the newest feature added to the bot.')

    if chnl == 'chatbot':
      send(message,str(message.content),'Cleverbot:')
      
      

    

    



#muting system



   
  



keep_alive()

TOKEN = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: Not **all** of my code works, but I am only concerned about the chatbot for now

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? What's your question?

Comment: @ForceBru, I have just edited the post to better specify, **my question is, how or what can I use to make a feature in where, there is a channel called "chatbot", and any text typed there would be replied to by Cleverbot**

Comment: That question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to [edit] your question to be more specific and ask about a problem you had with your attempt _after_ you do some debugging.